# Should i use the Reimann sum to solve this? $\int{\rm} x \sin(x) \, dx $

Tags: calculus

So I am trying to solve this equation and I am torn between if I should use the Reimann sum to solve it or not. My first steps are below but as maths can be tricky am yet sure if it is the right thing I am doing. Any help appreciated

$$\int{\rm} x \sin(x) \, dx $$

What I tried is :

$$u=x, \quad dv =\sin(x) dx$$
$$du = dx, \quad v=-\cos(x)$$ and I got stuck because I don't know if I should use the Reimann sum. Help or hints needed.

Comment: I don't think you can use a Riemann sum unless you have a definite integral (which you don't).  However, you look like you're on the right track.  You just need to finish by writing down what the integration by parts formula tells you and compute the last easy integral.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use integration by parts, which is exactly what you're supposed to do.  What made you think to go back to Riemann sums?

Comment: You're exactly on the right track. If you know how to do parts, then the rest is just super basic calculus.

Comment: now use $\int u dv  = uv - \int v du = -x\cos(x)+\int \cos(x)dx$

Comment: @TravisJ mind explaining that?

Comment: @user249954, do you mean explain how to finish with integration by parts?  I'd be happy to if that's the question.  Alonso Delfin gave the formula, you can use that.  All that remains is to compute $\int \cos(x)dx$.

Comment: yes please, i dont know @madona arrived with the answer. I would want a good explanation as i understand why i thought of the riemann sum. Thank you.

Comment: @user249954 Why are you thinking about Riemann sums?  When's the last time you computed an integral using Riemann sums?

Comment: I came across several examples and i saw someone saing they should use the Riemann sum to solve it, given n=terms but my question is how can you differentiate? I want to ask my teacher once back in school currently we are on break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

The answer will be:

$$-x cosx + sinx + C$$

You should use a Riemann sum when you have a definite integral, which in your case you dont.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I said integration by parts

$u=x, \quad dv =\sin(x) dx$

$du = dx, \quad v=-\cos(x)$

then $\int{\rm} x \sin(x) \, dx$ = $-xcosx + \int{\rm} co sX \, dx$

which = -x cosx + sinx + C